# I have a console error: react-dom.development.js:14887 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to display a list of workout items, but for some reason I'm getting an error

"react-dom.development.js:14887 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Error]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

There components of my code:

Workout jsx:

```
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query"
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom"
import cn from 'clsx'
import styles from './Workout.module.scss'
import stylesLayout from '../../layout/Layout.module.scss'
import Header from "../../layout/header/Header"
import Alert from "../../ui/alert/Alert"
import workoutLogService from "../../../services/workout/workout-log.service"
import Loader from "../../ui/Loader"
import ExerciseItem from "./ExerciseItem"
import { Fragment } from "react"

const Workout = () => {
  const {id} = useParams()

  const {data: workoutLog, isSuccess, isLoading} = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['get workout log', id],
    queryFn: () => workoutLogService.getById(id),
    select: ({data}) => data
  })

  return (
  <>
    <div 
     className={cn(stylesLayout.wrapper, stylesLayout.otherPage)}
     style={{ backgroundImage: `url('/images/workout-bg.jpg')`, height: 356}}
    >
      <Header backLink="/workouts" />

      {isSuccess && (
        <div>
          <time className={styles.time}>{workoutLog.minute + ' min.'}</time>
          <h1 className={stylesLayout.heading}>{workoutLog.workout.name}</h1>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
    <div
     className="wrapper-inner-page"
     style={{ paddingLeft: 0, paddingRight: 0 }}
    >
      <div style={{ width: '90%', margin: '0 auto'}}>
        {/* {errorCompleted && <Alert type="error" text={errorCompleted}/>} */}
      </div>
      {isLoading ? <Loader /> : 
        <div className={styles.wrapper}>
          {workoutLog?.exerciseLogs?.map((exerciseLog, index) => (
            <Fragment key={exerciseLog.id}>
              <ExerciseItem exerciseLog={exerciseLog}/>
              {index % 2 !== 0 && index !== workoutLog.exerciseLog.length - 1 && 
              (<div className={styles.line}/>)}
            </Fragment>
          ))}
        </div>
      }
    </div>
  </>
  )
}

export default Workout
```

List of workouts jsx:

```
import Layout from '../../layout/Layout'
import Loader from '../../ui/Loader'
import Alert from '../../ui/alert/Alert'
import styles from './Workout.module.scss'
import WorkoutItem from './WorkoutItem'
import { useWorkouts } from './useWorkouts'

const ListWorkouts = () => {
  const {data, error, isLoading, isSuccess, isSuccessMutate, mutate} = useWorkouts()

  return (
  <>
    <Layout bgImage='/images/workout-bg.jpg' heading='Workout list' />

    <div
      className='wrapper-inner-page'
      style={{paddingLeft: 0, paddingRight: 0}}
    >
      {error && <Alert type='error' text={error}/>}
      {isSuccessMutate && <Alert text='Workout log created'/>}
      {isLoading && <Loader />}
      {isSuccess && (
        <div className={styles.wrapper}>
          {data.map(workout => (
            <WorkoutItem key={workout.id} workout={workout} mutate={mutate}/>
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
      {isSuccess && data?.length === 0 && (
        <Alert type='warning' text='Workouts not found'/>
      )}
    </div>
  </>
  )
}

export default ListWorkouts
```

Exercise item jsx:

```
import cn from 'clsx'
import styles from './Workout.module.scss'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

const ExerciseItem = ({exerciseLog}) => {

  const navigation = useNavigate()

  return (
    <div  
    className={cn(styles.item, {
      [styles.completed]: exerciseLog.isCompleted,
    })}>
      <button aria-label='Move to exercise'
      onClick={() => navigation(`/exercise/${exerciseLog.id}`)}>
        <span>{exerciseLog.exercise.name}</span>
        <img 
        src={import.meta.env.VITE_SERVER_URL + exerciseLog.exercise.iconPath}
        height='34' 
        alt=""
        draggable = {false} />
      </button>
    </div>
    )
}

export default ExerciseItem
```

Workout item jsx:

```
import styles from './Workout.module.scss'

const WorkoutItem = ({ workout, mutate }) => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.item}>
      <button
      aria-label='Create new workout'
      onClick={() => mutate(workout.id)}
      >
        <span>{workout.name}</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default WorkoutItem
```

useWorkouts.js:

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"
import workoutService from "../../../services/workout/workout.service"
import workoutLogService from "../../../services/workout/workout-log.service"
import { useMutation, useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query"

export const useWorkouts = () => {
  const {data, isSuccess} = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['get workouts'], 
    queryFn: () => workoutService.getAll(),
    select: ({ data }) => data
  })

  const navigate = useNavigate()

  const {mutate, isLoading, isSuccess: isSuccessMutate, error} = useMutation({
    mutationKey: ['create new workout log'],
    mutationFn: (workoutId) => {workoutLogService.create(workoutId)},
    onSuccess: (data) => {
      navigate(`/workout/${data.id}`)
    }
  })

  return {
    data,
    isSuccess,
    mutate,
    isLoading,
    isSuccessMutate,
    error
  }
}
```

The error:

```
react-dom.development.js:14887 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Error]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    at throwOnInvalidObjectType (react-dom.development.js:14887:9)
    at reconcileChildFibers2 (react-dom.development.js:15828:7)
    at reconcileChildren (react-dom.development.js:19167:28)
    at updateHostComponent (react-dom.development.js:19924:3)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21618:14)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback2 (react-dom.development.js:4164:14)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:16)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:31)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:7)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:12)
```